# Collections.max method type parameters declaration signature <T extends Comparable<? super T>> explanation

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

In the **Java Generics by Naftalin and wadler** in chapter 3 **comparison  and Bounds** , it takes the example of **Collections.max** method as

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

and

```
<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

second signature is in Java api (for backward compatibility).

As per the Get -put principle I do understand the **Producer extends** and **consumer super** .

Now this take an example as follows:

```
abstract class Fruit {
    protected String name;
    protected int size;
    protected Fruit(String name, int size) {
        this.name = name; this.size = size;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Fruit) {
        Fruit that = (Fruit)o;
        return this.name.equals(that.name) && this.size == that.size;
        } else return false;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode()*29 + size;
    }
    protected int compareTo(Fruit that) {
        return this.size < that.size ? -1 :
        this.size == that.size ? 0 : 1 ;
    }

}
class Apple extends Fruit implements Comparable<Apple> {
    public Apple(int size) {
         super("Apple", size); 
    }
public int compareTo(Apple a) { 
    return super.compareTo(a); 
    }
}
class Orange extends Fruit implements Comparable<Orange> {
    public Orange(int size) { 
        super("Orange", size); 
    }
public int compareTo(Orange o) {
         return super.compareTo(o);
     }
}
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apple a1 = new Apple(1); 
    Apple a2 = new Apple(2);
    Orange o3 = new Orange(3); 
    Orange o4 = new Orange(4);
    List<Apple> apples = Arrays.asList(a1,a2);
    assert Collections.max(apples).equals(a2);
    List<Orange> oranges = Arrays.asList(o3,o4);
    assert Collections.max(oranges).equals(o4);
    List<Fruit> mixed = Arrays.<Fruit>asList(a1,o3);
    assert Collections.max(mixed).equals(o3); // compile-time error
    }
}
```

Now it says :

This example shows why this wildcard is needed. If we want to compare two
oranges, we take T in the preceding code to be Orange:

```
Orange extends Comparable<? super Orange>
```

And this is true because both of the following hold:

```
Orange extends Comparable<Fruit> and Fruit super Orange
```

Without the super wildcard, finding the maximum of a `List<Orange>` would be illegal,
even though finding the maximum of a `List<Fruit>` is permitted

I do understand everything in this example except the line **Without the super wildcard, finding the maximum of a `List<Orange>` would be illegal**

I am finding myself in unclear situation . However I have gone many answers at stackoverflow explaining the Collections.max method signature(and I do understand that signature, might be not completely).

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: why it would not legal to find max from List<Orange> means what problem it will face if type definition of t is specified as <T extends Comparable<T>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misquoting the book. The statement was made about the case where `Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>`. In such a case, `Orange` would not be a valid candidate for `<T extends Comparable<T>>` because `Orange` doesn't implement `Comparable<Orange>`. Therefore, you can't pass a `List<Orange>` as `List<T>` unless `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`, which ensures that one `Orange` can be compared to another by means of the `Fruit` superclass.

Comment: I think that was the confusion ,I had . I was not able to identify that statement "Without the super wildcard, finding the maximum of a List<Orange> would be illegal, even though finding the maximum of a List<Fruit> is permitted" was with respect to first example where Fruit implementing Comparable